# org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding SecurityException

Tags: java, jsp, jboss5.x

Running jboss EAP 5.2, java 6, linux VM server.

One of 8 of my production server threw this error while trying to compile the login jsp:

Unexpected error during load of:org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

I can see I have this class in 2 jar files inside my project:
jdtcore-3.1.0.jar (which I am getting from jasperreport 4.1)
ecj-3.5.1.jar (which I am getting from drools-compiler 5.3)

I didn't get this error in any of my testing in lower environments and am only getting it on one of 8 should be identically jboss servers.

It seems likely the versions of these 2 jars are not compatible but I could not find that much information on them or which to exclude and as I have no way to reproduce the error I can't really fix it with trial and error.

Any suggestion on if I should exclude one of these jars from my project or if there is a set of compatible versions for these jars?

Comment: Jasperreports 6 uses ECJ and not JDT but upgrading from 4 to 6 will take time, my project has like 300 reports and I know we identified some changes needed to go to jasper 5.  I suspect I can just exclude JDT and ECJ will work but I can't make the issue happen so can't be sure.  I also verified neither of the jars I am using in my ear are signed so I am not sure where I am getting a signed jar, the jboss common libs I assume but have not found it.

Comment: I found a signed jar jasper-jdt.jar in jbossweb.sar but I am not sure if that would be in my classpath.  It looks like a newer version of jdtcore but I don't know how to say for sure.